# LINQ: How to Use RemoveAll without using For loop with Array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, removeall

I currently have a log object I'd like to remove objects from, based on a LINQ query. I would like to remove all records in the log if the sum of the versions within a program are greater than 60. Currently I'm pretty confident that this'll work, but it seems kludgy:

```
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        {
          Log.RemoveAll(log =>
                    (log.Program[index].Version[0].Value +
                     log.Program[index].Version[1].Value +
                     log.Program[index].Version[2].Value ) > 60);
        }
```

The Program is an array of 4 values and version has an array of 3 values. Is there a more simple way to do this RemoveAll in LINQ without using the for loop?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately the type of variable that Program and Version are based off of (which is a constraint of the  framework I'm working in) restricts us such that I cannot access the "Any" member. I however confirmed that tzaman's solution works if you have *lists* by creating some sample code. I'm restricted to array-like variables (see the commented out areas)

```
// I'm restricted to Arrays, but if I had lists, this would work. 
  internal class MyLogCollection
  {
    List<MyLog> MyListOfZones = new List<MyLog>();

    public void TestRemove()
    {
      // Original Implementation
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        MyListOfZones.RemoveAll(log => (log.MyZoneArray[0].MyVersionArray[0].Value +
                                        log.MyZoneArray[0].MyVersionArray[1].Value +
                                        log.MyZoneArray[0].MyVersionArray[2].Value) > 60);
        //"Any" method is not available off of intellisense scope on MyZoneArray 
      }

      // Better Implementation (thanks tzaman!)
      MyListOfZones.RemoveAll(log => (log.MyZoneArray.Any(prog =>
                                                          prog.MyVersionArray.Sum(ver => ver.Value) > 60)));
    }
  }
  internal class MyLog
  {
    //public MyZone[] MyZoneArray = new MyZone[4];

    public List<MyZone> MyZoneArray = new List<MyZone>(4);

  }
  internal class MyZone
  {
    //public MyVersion[] MyVersionArray = new MyVersion[3];
    public List<MyVersion> MyVersionArray = new List<MyVersion>(3);
  }
  internal class MyVersion
  {
    public byte Value { get; set;}

  }
```

Thanks tzaman!

Comment: Just `Any` doesn't work, or none of the LINQ operators work? Is it a regular `System.Array` type, or some custom type with an overloaded indexing operator? If the latter, you won't be able to use LINQ afaik, unless you can get an `IEnumerable` out of it somehow. You could pretty easily define an extension method to do that for you (using a for-loop and `yield return`)... if you need an example I could update my answer.

Comment: @tzaman - sorry for the late reply - none of the operators work. It is an "array like" object, I'm 90% confident its not a System Array type. I know its not IEnumerable right now :-/. If you do know how to create an IEnumerable, I would greatly appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it, I think:

```
Log.RemoveAll(log => 
              log.Program.Any(prog => 
                              prog.Version.Sum(ver => ver.Value) > 60));
```

**EDIT:** Okay, so here's how to add extension methods to get `IEnumerable`s from your indexable "array-like" objects, so that you can use LINQ on them:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<MyZone> Enumerate(this MyZoneArray zone)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < zone.Length; i++)
            yield return zone[i];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyVersion> Enumerate(this MyVersionArray version)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < version.Length; i++)
            yield return version[i]
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the `MyZoneArray` and `MyVersionArray` types have a `Length` field, but if not you could just put in `4` and `3` over there. With these in place, you can now call the `Enumerate()` function on the collection object to get an `IEnumerable` version of the collection, with all the associated LINQy goodness attached: `log.MyZoneArray.Enumerate().Any( ... )`

Comment: Gah!  Too fast for me.  Nice answer :)

Comment: Hmmm. For some reason the "Any" method isn't available to me off of the Program Variable. Your solution may work properly, but I attempted to test it with another group of arrays and it didn't work properly. I think if I used lists (or had the flexibility to use lists in my implementation) instead of arrays it'd work properly.

Comment: That's odd, though; `Any` is a standard LINQ method and it should be available on any array object. Does it work on `Version`?