# Removing item from a Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, generic-list

I'm trying to remove an item from a `Generic List` which is bound to a repeater control.

So far I've got a remove method (after scouring the interwebs) that should of been working:

```
Label lblMemberName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMemberName");        

switch (e.CommandName)
{
    case "RemoveMember":
        foreach (challenge.Member member in Members.Where(member => member.Name == lblMemberName.Text))
        {
            //This line doesnt work
            Members.Remove(member);
        }
        break;
}
```

Unfortunately, the actual removal apart of this scenario is not working.

I understand that you can't create a `new` instance of a `List<>` to delete. So, that's why I used the `Linq` statement to find the previous details.

What am I doing wrong and how could possibly ix it?

Comment: Copy the result of linq to a new list, then remove each item from Members.

Comment: @L.B tried to create a new instance of challenge.Member , copy the Linq statement to it, then remove that new isntance from Members - Doesnt work.

Comment: Did you append a `.ToList()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As above, you cannot modify the contents of a collection whilst iterating over it.

You could also try [List(T).RemoveAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx). Refer to [LINQ: How to Use RemoveAll without using For loop with Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884403/linq-how-to-use-removeall-without-using-for-loop-with-array). This is a more succinct solution than another list.

Comment: It seems as if i will need to know the size of the `Generic List` for that to work?

Comment: No, not really. Should be as simple as Members.RemoveAll(Members.Where(member => member.Name == lblMemberName.Text));

Comment: @NewAmbition, Cal: No, it's `Members.RemoveAll(member => member.Name == lblMemberName.Text);`, it takes the predicate directly.

Comment: \:D/ Love all around.. Testing the other code, i managed to just remove everything >.<... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Good spot. +1 Rawling. Half asleep this morning. Glad it worked in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's illegal to modify the list you're foreach-ing through. You can, however, convert it to a for-loop instead of foreach, and modify it then.

```
for (int i=0; i < Members.Count; i++)
{
    if (Members[i].Name == lblMemberName.Text)
        Members.RemoveAt(i--); // decrement because we just shrunk the list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the member:

```
var member = Members.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Name.Equals(thename));
```

And then remove it from list:

```
if (member != null) 
{ 
    Members.Remove(member); 
}
```